# CommandLineRunner required a bean that could not be found

Tags: spring, api

I'm new to making APIs and Spring in general.

I'm trying to use CommandLineRunner in order to populate my repository but it says that it cannot find the required bean that I put in the parameter.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initializeDB(StudentRepository studentRepository){
        return (args)->{
            studentRepository.save(new Student("John1", "Doe1", "asdasda1","Comp Sci1",21));
            studentRepository.save(new Student("John2", "Doe2", "asdasda2","Comp Sci2",22));
            studentRepository.save(new Student("John3", "Doe3", "asdasda3","Comp Sci3",23));
            studentRepository.save(new Student("John4", "Doe4", "asdasda4","Comp Sci4",24));
            studentRepository.save(new Student("John5", "Doe5", "asdasda5","Comp Sci5",25));
            studentRepository.save(new Student("John6", "Doe6", "asdasda6","Comp Sci6",26));
            logger.info("The sample data has been generated");
        };
    }
}
```

That is my application class and below is my repository class.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.model.Student;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
}
```

Is there a basic thing that I am missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the package structure of your classes? Is the StudentRepository in the same or a subpackage as your application class?

Comment: StudentRepository is in its own package Repository and Application class is under its own package Applicaiton. Both the packages are both in the same src/main/java folder

Comment: Any other classes for which you wanted spring to manage its bean's lifecycle, move that to a (sub)package of DemoApplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Easiest and wise thing to do

DemoApplication (or whichever class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) should reside at the root of the package structure

That means, for any other classes for which you want spring to manage it's bean's lifecycle, move that to a (sub)package of DemoApplication.

In other words, if your DemoApplication is in a package src/main/java/com/yourorg then StudentRepository should be in a (sub)package of src/main/java/com/yourorg

Comment: That's it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the application class is not in a super package as the other classes, you have to specify all packages in the `SpringBootApplication`, which should be scanned (for component scanning, Spring Data repositories etc.).

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"package1", "package2"})
```

or for a typesafe approach

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {ClassFromPackage1.class, ClassFromPackage2.class})
```

Alternatively move all packages to a subpackage of the application class package, so that all the default mechanisms take place.